# Left join and wildcard not returning results?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

This is my query. Essentially, I want to retrieve value `@Remote.ImportantVal` by using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
declare @Local table
(
    LocalId varchar(15),
    Match1 int,
    Match2 varchar(5)
)
insert into @local select '12_012_112', 5, 'MATH'
insert into @local select '12_012_113', 5, 'MATH'
insert into @local select '12_012_114', 5, 'MATH'

declare @Remote table
(
    RemoteId varchar(15),
    ImportantVal varchar(20),
    Match1 int,
    Match2 varchar(5)
)   
insert into @Remote select 'ABC0012_012_112', 'Important', 5, 'MATH'
insert into @Remote select 'ABC0112_012_113', 'Important', 5, 'MATH'
insert into @Remote select 'ABC0012_012_114', 'Important', 5, 'MATH'

select l.localId, r.RemoteId, r.ImportantVal
from @Local l left join @Remote r on 'ABC%' + l.LocalId like r.RemoteId
and l.Match1 = r.Match1
and r.Match2 = r.Match2
```

It seems the issue is the `%`, but it's needed because the 2 characters after *ABC* will never be the same. In the previous query, the two tables do not match and it returns 3 empty rows.

If I use something like this, then only 2 rows match, since it's basically an `inner join`:

```
select l.localId, r.RemoteId, r.ImportantVal
from @Local l left join @Remote r on 'ABC00' + l.LocalId like r.RemoteId
and l.Match1 = r.Match1
and r.Match2 = r.Match2
```

I've also tried the `left join` with the `where` clause, but that just converts it to an `inner join` so nothing's returned:

```
select l.localId, r.RemoteId, r.ImportantVal
from @Local l left join @Remote r on 'ABC%' + l.LocalId like r.RemoteId
where l.Match1 = r.Match1
and r.Match2 = r.Match2
```

Using `left join` and `%`, how can I match all three rows in both tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of the arguments in the join clause:

```
from @Local l left join @Remote r on r.RemoteId like 'ABC%' + l.LocalId
```

and you should get the three rows you expect. (At least my test gives this).

The wildcard has to be used in the pattern on the right hand side of the like expression as stated in the documentation:

> match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]

Comment: Is that some sort of bug? It doesn't make sense that a result set would change simply because of the order of the arguments.

Comment: @rbhatup As far as I know it's by design and certainly not a bug. It's just how the operator is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the join as two different clauses in your `WHERE`;

Sample Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #Local (LocalId varchar(15), Match1 int, Match2 varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #Local 
VALUES 
('12_012_112', 5, 'MATH')
,('12_012_113', 5, 'MATH')
,('12_012_114', 5, 'MATH')

CREATE TABLE #Remote (RemoteId varchar(15), ImportantVal varchar(20), Match1 int, Match2 varchar(5))   
INSERT INTO #Remote 
VALUES
('ABC0012_012_112', 'Important', 5, 'MATH')
,('ABC0112_012_113', 'Important', 5, 'MATH')
,('ABC0012_012_114', 'Important', 5, 'MATH')
```

Actual query;

```
SELECT
l.LocalId
,r.RemoteId
,r.ImportantVal
FROM #Local l
LEFT JOIN #Remote r
ON r.RemoteId LIKE 'ABC%'
AND l.LocalID = RIGHT(r.RemoteId,LEN(l.LocalId))
AND l.Match1 = r.Match1
AND l.Match2 = r.Match2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
select l.localId, r.RemoteId, r.ImportantVal
from @Local l left join @Remote r on RIGHT(l.LocalId,10) = r.RemoteId
and l.Match1 = r.Match1
and r.Match2 = r.Match2
```

OR, if the "ABC" is significant, then

```
select l.localId, r.RemoteId, r.ImportantVal
from @Local l left join @Remote r on RIGHT(l.LocalId,10) = r.RemoteId
and l.LocalId like 'ABC%'
and l.Match1 = r.Match1
and r.Match2 = r.Match2
```